# sql select all users from table X which are not in comination on table Y

Tags: php, sql, select, medoo

I'm fairly new to sql and am trying to get data from table X when the user is not in table Y with the combination of player id and world id AND the player access is 2.

Let me explain a little furter:

Table X (user table)

```
+-----------+----------+------------+
| uid       | access   |  more data |
+-----------+----------+------------+
| 1         | 2        |    ....    |
| 2         | 1        |    ....    |
| 3         | 2        |    ....    |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

Table Y (worlds)

```
+-----------+-----------+
| userUuid  | worldUuid |
+-----------+-----------+
| 1         | 1         |
| 2         | 2         |
| 3         | 2         |
+-----------+-----------+
```

When I want to get all users which I can still add to world 1 I want to get the user info from user 3.

User 1 already is in world 1, user 2 does not have access level 2 and user 3 isn't in world 1 yet and does have access level 2.

I'm using medoo and this is my statement at the moment:

```
$database->select("User", [
    "[>]UserInWorld" => ["uid" => "userUid"]
], [
    "uid",
    "displayname",
    "surname",
    "email"
], [
    "AND" => [
        "worldUuid[!]" => $worldUuid,
        "access" => 2
    ]
]);
```

The worldUuid will be the world I want to get user to add for.

When use the ->debug() the query looks like this:

```
SELECT "uid","displayname","surname","email" 
FROM "User" 
LEFT JOIN "UserInWorld" ON "User"."uid" = "UserInWorld"."userUid" 
WHERE "worldUuid" != '4dafb8c0-57234ff2-03eb-af7f7a5e' 
AND "access" = 2
```

EDIT: I posted a sollution using medoo below

Comment: But from your sample seems you want the userUid  with level access = 2 not in User .. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good night sleep I figured out how to do this using the medoo class

```
$database->select("User", [
    "[>]UserInWorld" => ["uid" => "userUid"]
], [
    "uid",
    "displayname",
    "surname",
    "email"
], [
    "AND" => [
        "OR" => [
            "worldUuid[!]" => [$worldUuid],
            "worldUuid" => NULL
        ],
        "access" => 2
    ],
    "GROUP" => "uid"
]);
```

Whereby the $worldUuid the world is I want to select users for.

This will make the following sql statement:

```
SELECT "uid","displayname","surname","email" FROM "User" 
LEFT JOIN "UserInWorld" ON "User"."uid" = "UserInWorld"."userUid" 
WHERE ("worldUuid" NOT IN ('1') OR "worldUuid" IS NULL) 
AND "access" = 2
GROUP BY "uid"
```

This will select all (unique) user who do not have a world already OR are in the world I'm getting users for AND they have access level 2

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you should be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT
    uid,
    displayname,
    surname,
    email 
FROM
    User
    LEFT JOIN UserInWorld ON User.uid = UserInWorld.userUid AND worldUuid = 1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            userUid
        from
            UserInWorld
        WHERE
            worldUuid != 1
    ) AS InOtherWorld ON InOtherWorld.userUid = User.uid
WHERE
    access = 2
    AND UserInWorld.userUid IS NULL
```

The left join will connect people in the world where possible and then `UserInWorld.userUid IS NULL` will effectively strip it down to those that aren't in the world.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I also want to get users which already do have connection in table Y. I just don't want to get users which already are in table Y with a specific world. (users can be added  to multiple worlds)

Comment: I've added another join to only include people who are already in a different world.

Comment: Thanks for your help, after a good night sleep I figured out a way to do this in medoo. WIll update my post

Answer (score 0):

you said:

> am trying to get data from table X when the user is not in table Y with the combination of player id and world id AND the player access is 2

If I've understood it should be:

```
select * from X where X.access = 2 and X.uid not in (
    select Y.userUuid from Y
)
```

Comment: They can be in table Y allready, just not in combination with worldUuid X

Comment: If you mean: select all users with access = 2 AND with a corrispondence in worldUuid you just have to change Y.userUuid to Y.worldUuid in my code's answer